# Is it possible to fill an ArrayList with Console.ReadLine?

Tags: c#, arraylist, readline

I'm trying to fill my ArrayList with Console.ReadLine. Unfortunately, I always get an error. Is there another possibility?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
            names.Add() = Console.ReadLine();
            names.Add() = Console.ReadLine();
            names.Add() = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, it's recommended to use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` where you can define the expected item type for better compile-time error checking.

Comment: Saying _"always get an error"_ doesn't provide much information. What error? When?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is entirely wrong. You're trying to assign a value to a method invocation (`names.Add()`), which is not possible. What you want to do is pass the contents of `Console.ReadLine()` *into the method invocation* as a parameter:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
            names.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            names.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            names.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

Now, this code is also not very good as you could enter invalid input or not enter anything at all. Ideally your code would be performing some kind of validation to ensure you're only adding values you really want to add into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a methode, instead you have to give the value to the methode inside the parenthes like this.
names.Add(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   ArrayList names = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine ("type ? to exit")
    var name=string.Empty;
    do
    {
         name =Console.ReadLine();
         if(name!="?")  names.Add(name );
        
    } while(name!="?")
```